# letter changer lowercase to uppercase(vice versa) : Whats wrong in my code?

Tags: python-2.7

I wanted to enter a word with upperandlower letter combination letters and then when i press enter it will change vice versa

```
def changer(word):
for letter in word:
    if letter.isupper():
     letter.lower()
    elif letter.islower():
        letter.upper()
print word
```

word = raw_input()
changer(word)

Comment: ...you do not return anything to word. and strings in python are immutable; you can not change them in-place.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist sir even i replace print with return keyword same output.

Answer (score 0):

You must append the converted letters to new string, and returning the new string could be helpful, too.

```
def changer(word):
    newWord = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter.isupper():
            newWord += letter.lower()
        elif letter.islower():
            newWord += letter.upper()
    print newWord
    return newWord
```

Answer (score 0):

...you do not return anything. and strings in python are immutable; you can not change them in-place.

this is something you could try:

```
def swapcase(word):
    return ''.join(c.lower() if c.isupper() else c.upper() for c in word)

print(swapcase(word='Hello'))  # hELLO
```

where i use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) to join the generator that iterates over the characters with the swapped case.

---

speed-wise [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.translate) may be the better choice:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

trans_table = str.maketrans(ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase,
                            ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase)

def swapcase(word):

    return word.translate(trans_table)

print('Hello'.translate(trans_table))  # hELLO
```

Comment: Thank you...More power to you sir